# how do i fix my fruit machine so the symbols change each time and the credit only goes to decimal places?

Tags: python

so this is a program which is supposed to be a fruit machine.

The problem i have is that on the goes after the first the same symbols keep appearing and also the credit turns into a decimal number which is more than 2decimal places.

The credit is supposed to resemble money so only 2 decimal places can be allowed.

```
`import random

Symbols = ["Cherry", "Bell", "Lemon", "Orange", "Star", "Skull"] #list of available symbols
Credit = (1.00) #set the users start credit to £1
Output1 = []
Output2 = []
Output3 = []
Outputs = [Output1, Output2, Output3]

while Credit >0.00:

    User_Input = input("Would you like a game?")

    if User_Input == "yes":
        Output1.append(random.choice(Symbols))
        Output2.append(random.choice(Symbols))
        Output3.append(random.choice(Symbols))
        Credit = Credit-0.20

        if (Output1 == Output2) or (Output1 == Output3) or (Output2 == Output3): #if 2 of the symbols are the same
            if (Output1 == "Skull" and Output2 == "Skull" and Output3 != "Skull") or (Output1 == "Skull" and Output3 == "Skull" and Output2 != "Skull") or (Output2 == "Skull" and Output3 == "Skull" and Output1 != "Skull"):
            #if 2 of the symbols are skulls and the other is not
            Credit = Credit-1.00 #user loses £1 if two skulls are shown
        Credit = Credit+0.50

    elif (Output1 == Output2) and (Output2 == Output3): #if all symbols match
        if (Output1 == "Bell") and (Output2 == "Bell") and (Output3 == "Bell"): #if all the symbols are bells
            Credit = Credit+5.00 #user earns £5 if 3 bells are shown
        Credit = Credit+1.00

    else: #if symbols are different
        Credit =Credit #if all symbols are different user earns no money

    print ("Your symbols are", Outputs)
    print ("Your Credit now is", Credit)
    Output1 = []
    Output2 = []
    Output3 = []

else: #if the user doesnt type in yes
    Credit = 0.00

if Credit <= 0.00: #when the user doesnt have any credit
    print("End of game Goodbye")`
```

Comment: There are some identation errors which make the logic of the game hard to follow. Can you explain the expected behavior a bit in more detail and check identations! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from a very difficult to follow logic,the main issue with this function is that the variable `outputs` is declared once at the beginning of the function and then never again.

```
import random

Symbols = ["Cherry", "Bell", "Lemon", "Orange", "Star", "Skull"] #list of available symbols
Credit = (1.00) #set the users start credit to £1

while Credit >0.00:

User_Input = input("Would you like a game?")

if User_Input == "yes":
    Output1=random.choice(Symbols)
    Output2=random.choice(Symbols)
    Output3=random.choice(Symbols)
    Outputs = [Output1,Output2,Output3]
    Credit-=0.20

    if (Output1 == Output2) or (Output1 == Output3) or (Output2 == Output3): #if 2 of the symbols are the same
        if (Output1 == "Skull" and Output2 == "Skull" and Output3 != "Skull") or (Output1 == "Skull" and Output3 == "Skull" and Output2 != "Skull") or (Output2 == "Skull" and Output3 == "Skull" and Output1 != "Skull"):
        #if 2 of the symbols are skulls and the other is not
        Credit = Credit-1.00 #user loses £1 if two skulls are shown
    Credit = Credit+0.50

elif (Output1 == Output2) and (Output2 == Output3): #if all symbols match
    if (Output1 == "Bell") and (Output2 == "Bell") and (Output3 == "Bell"): #if all the symbols are bells
        Credit = Credit+5.00 #user earns £5 if 3 bells are shown
    Credit = Credit+1.00

else: #if symbols are different
    Credit =Credit #if all symbols are different user earns no money

print ("Your symbols are", Outputs)
print ("Your Credit now is", Credit)

else: #if the user doesnt type in yes
    Credit = 0.00

if Credit <= 0.00: #when the user doesnt have any credit
    print("End of game Goodbye")
```